# Leaflet | Polygon - No se visualiza el polígono

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Tras añadir un polígono en el mapa, no se visualiza el polígono, pero sí el mapa.
¿La función polygon() funciona automñaticamente con Leaflet, o hay que instalar algún plugin?

**Código:**

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
    [41.31969151691418, -2.0050252292003146],
    [41.31837782687788, -2.006361323222095],
    [41.31992457790886, -2.007465153394784]
]);

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays, polygon).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Puedes probar con `var poly = L.polygon(polygon).addTo(map);`

Comment: Perfecto gracias. ¿y para poner un title por ejemplo en el centro de ese polígono es posible?

Comment: Tienes el método `bindTooltip`. `poly.bindTooltip("Un title cualquiera", {permanent: true, direction:"center"})`

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera se visualiza sin ningún problema:

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(mymap);
```

Enlace de información:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/